# how to create vbs file to execute bat file in the following path C:\Program Files (x86)\ACCESSDOIP\VPN\connect.bat

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, path

I need to run a batch file existing in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\ACCESSDOIP\VPN`. I've made a VBScript file and tried hard to add the path, but it shows error.

Please can you write me the correct path mentioning that the full path with the file name is like that:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ACCESSDOIP\VPN\connect.bat
```

Comment: When asking questions on SO you should show what you have already tried, and what results that produced, including all error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an error, because you're trying to run the file like this:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\ACCESSDOIP\VPN\connect.bat"
```

That won't work, because the path contains spaces, so you must put it in additional double quotes (the double quotes in the above code just form a string in VBScript). The inner double quotes must be escaped (lest they prematurely terminate the string) by doubling them.

Try this:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\ACCESSDOIP\VPN\connect.bat"""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\ACCESSDOIP\VPN\connect.bat"
```

try that...